# Read XML tag and export XML file name to Excel using BATCH program

Tags: xml, excel, csv, batch-file

Can anyone help to write the BATCH program to read the tag element value from XML file and if that value matched with the one you need then export the name of XML file to Excel.

suppose in folder there are 20 XML files, this script should read the specific tag element value from XML file and based on that it should export the XML file name to excel/csv/txt. so may be output txt/csv/excel file will have 5 xml file name which matches your criteria

ex. Folder TEST have 20 XML files, test1.xml, test2.xml and so on...

test1.xml sample would be like below...we need to check  value and  based on that export the name of the file to text/csv/excel.....

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<sh:StandardBusinessDocumentHeader>
    <sh:HeaderVersion>1.0</sh:HeaderVersion>
    -<sh:Sender>
        <sh:Identifier>3015060500992</sh:Identifier>
    </sh:Sender>
    -<sh:Receiver>
        <sh:Identifier>4539594000005</sh:Identifier>
    </sh:Receiver>
    -<sh:DocumentIdentification>
        <sh:Standard>EAN.UCC</sh:Standard>
        <sh:TypeVersion>2.5</sh:TypeVersion>
        <sh:InstanceIdentifier>SBDH_4539594000005_tt7x7c71fof8d9adenhr</sh:InstanceIdentifier>
        <sh:Type>multiShipmentOrder</sh:Type>
        <sh:MultipleType>false</sh:MultipleType>
        <sh:CreationDateAndTime>2013-04-09T11:08:54</sh:CreationDateAndTime>
    </sh:DocumentIdentification>
</sh:StandardBusinessDocumentHeader>
```

Regards,
Parag

Comment: `read the specific tag element value` which one?

Comment: Don't do that in a batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
@echo off
echo. >export.txt
set searchid="<sh:InstanceIdentifier>SBDH_4539594000005_tt7x7c71fof8d9adenhr<"
for /f %%a in ('findstr /i /m %searchid% *.xml') do (
  echo %%a >>export.txt
)
```

Comment: Hi,Got one more issue....I am doing find string from folder which has "!" in the folder name....ex... based on above script on line no 5 if we have folder name like this 'findstr /i /m %searchid% c:\ABC!def\*.xml' ; it would not return anything. Could you please help how to consider the folder name having special character in it.

Comment: Hi, any idea how to handle special character ! in folder name

Comment: Try quoting the name, if that does not work, I suggest you open a new SO question